# ShoppingItem and ShoppingItemField tables are missing in liferay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-7

Is ShoppingItem and ShoppingItemField tables are removed from Liferay 7 ?. I was wondering because I have come from Liferay 6.2 and used these tables a lot !!!

Comment: I hope you didn't use "the tables" a lot, but rather utilized the API. If you used to manually write to the tables: Stop doing so - it's a recipe for disaster. Lots of arguments here: https://web.liferay.com/en/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/67044512

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but the Shopping Portlet is not yet present in Liferay 7.

It's removed from the core because it has not been mantained by long time.

Look at release notes in https://web.liferay.com/it/web/jamie.sammons/blog/-/blogs/liferay-portal-7-0-ce-release where Liferay talks about a shopping plugin version in the marketplace for the 7th but nobody has ever seen it.

Comment: Hi Daniele, thanks for the quick and nice reply. I have been using some porltets which are developed in Liferay 6.2 and used these classes a lot. I am trying to upgrade my portlets so they can run on liferay7. But here at this point, I stuck. Are there any other solutions for Shopping portlets in Liferay7?

Comment: You could create by yourself a custom service layer to emulate the shopping portlet, grabbing the code from 6.2 and porting it to 7....